# Class extension

Tags: python, oop, discord.py

When using `discord.py`, I need to extend the `discord.Guild` class and other similar classes. Normal inheritance doesn't fully work 'cause I need to be able to create an inherited class based on the original class.
Example:

```
from typing import Self


class BaseClass:
    a: int

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = 0

    def add(self) -> Self:
        self.a += 1
        return self


class ExtendedClass(BaseClass):
    @classmethod
    def from_base(cls, original: BaseClass):
        # Code to get data from base class
        ...
    
    def print(self):
        print(self.a)


obj1 = BaseClass()
obj1.add().add()
print(obj1.a)  # 2

obj2 = ExtendedClass.from_base(obj1)
obj2.print()  # 2
obj2.add().add().add()
obj2.print()  # 5
```

I use Python 3.11.4, virtual environment venv, Fedora workstation release 38, and discord.py version 2.3.0
Here's full code of the project: https://github.com/Tumpa-Prizrak/yadis-discord-bot/tree/architecture-fix

I tried to use __dict__:

```
from typing import Self
from models.dataclasses import Settings
import discord


class Guild(discord.Guild):
    settings: Settings
    is_blacklisted: bool

    @classmethod
    def from_discord(
        cls, guild: discord.Guild, settings: Settings, is_blacklisted: bool = False
    ) -> Self:
        obj: Self = cls.__new__(cls)

        obj.__dict__ = guild.__dict__
        obj.settings = settings
        obj.is_blacklisted = is_blacklisted

        return obj
```

But it turned out that `discord.Guild` did not have the __dict__ attribute and was getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<user>/Projects/yadis-discord-bot/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/<user>/Projects/yadis-discord-bot/src/bot/yadis.py", line 32, in on_ready
    print(api.get_guild(bot=self, guild=guild).name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/<user>/Projects/yadis-discord-bot/src/api/database/api.py", line 19, in get_guild
    return discord_models.Guild.from_discord(guild, settings_data, is_blacklisted=guild_data.blacklisted)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/<user>/Projects/yadis-discord-bot/src/models/discord_models/guild.py", line 16, in from_discord
    obj.__dict__ = guild.__dict__
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

I would also welcome any other solutions

Comment: yeah, you cannot rely on having a `__dict__`, note, even if you did, you should do `obj.__dict__.update(guild.__dict__)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following scheme worked for me: `inspect.getmembers` and `setattr`

Here's following code:

```py
from typing import Callable, Self
import inspect


class BaseClass:
    a: int

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = 0

    def add(self) -> Self:
        self.a += 1
        return self


class ExtendedClass(BaseClass):
    @classmethod
    def from_base(cls, original: BaseClass):
        obj: Self = cls.__new__(cls)

        for k, v in inspect.getmembers(original):
            if k.startswith("__"): continue
            if isinstance(v, Callable): continue
            obj.__setattr__(k, v)
            # print(f"{k}: {v}")
        
        return obj
    
    def print(self) -> Self:
        print(self.a)
        return self


obj1 = BaseClass()
obj1.add().add()
print(obj1.a)  # 2

obj2 = ExtendedClass.from_base(obj1)
obj2.print()  # 2
obj2.add().add().add()
obj2.print()  # 5
```

Maybe this method isn't fully right, but it's enough for me. You can freely criticise this code in the comments. I'll be happy to see reasons why this method wrong (if it's)